# How to create separate views depending on user of website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've created a project using code first.

I'm wanting to create two separate routes with separate layouts, and a shared database. And managing the separation by providing separate link from the launch and using User Authentication `[Authorize]` with the User Identity to assist in controlling which users can access which links.

This also gives the opportunity to present the employee website on the intranet.

However I do not want the consumer to be able to view these links at all.  So I am separating out the views and controllers.

For instance:
1. If the employee is accessing the site, the Index home page will be `AdminIndex`, using the `_AdminLayout`.
2. If the Customer is accessing the website, it will land on the `Index` using `_Layout`

[image: folders]

I'm sure there are better ways to do this.
Is it viable to package this within one project? Or is it better to separate them, in which case I am unsure how to share the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is screaming for multiple projects in the same solution.  How far you take it after that depends on the size of the project and your specific needs, but at the very least, consider something along the lines of the following:

```
SolutionName
- SolutionName.Admin
- SolutionName.DAL // Data Access Layer (DAL)
- SolutionName.Frontend / Web
```

The purpose of the DAL project is to centralise your data-related concerns in one place, which you would then reference from the other two projects.  You can take this a *lot* further, depending on the size, and complexity, of what you're working on, but the above will serve as a good starting point for a smaller project.

By doing the above, you'll make your code naturally cleaner, easier to test and maintain, simply because you won't have conditional checks littered throughout the code to determine if someone is an admin or not.

Comment: @Heyyou Not a problem - we're all still learning. :)  I remember this not being particularly clear to me when I first started out either, but you have a great example here as to why multiple projects, and a layered solution, can be useful.  If you're curious as to how far it can really be taken, it would be worth reading through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx).  In particular, chapters 5-9 cover the idea of layering.  There are other sources, of course, but it would undoubtedly give you things to research later on.

Comment: @Heyyou In that case, I wish you all the best for the exam.  I'm sure you'll be fine. :)